# unityで開発されたプログラムでゲーム以外だとどういうものがありますか？ゲームの印象ばかりが先行してしまいます。

Tags: unity3d

最近、趣味でunityの開発をしております。 
unity自体は楽しくて、簡単なゲーム作品を作っております。

ゲーム以外の開発をunityでやりたいなと日々思っておりますが、 
ゲーム以外で何がいいかなというのがあまり出てきませんでした。

書籍やネットでunity関連の内容だとどうしてもゲームよりの内容が多く、 
参考になる内容がすくなかったです。

そこで、皆さんのご意見を賜りたいです。

規模の大小、業界にかかわらず、ご回答いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

unityでつくったかどうかはわかりませんが、 
人体模型を3Dで再現させているのはunityでもできそうかなと思いました。

Comment: 「皆さんのご意見を賜りたい」と言った、明確な正解というもののないアンケート型の質問はこのサイトの趣旨には合わないのではないかと思います。[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)、[どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)。

Answer (score 0):

Unityサイトのギャラリーに、ゲーム以外の開発事例もいくつか上がってました。

「ギャラリー」
　　http://japan.unity3d.com/gallery/

「開発事例」（ゲーム以外の開発事例）
　　http://japan.unity3d.com/gallery/made-with-unity/solution

ジグソーパズルや言葉あそびなど半分ゲームのようなものも含まれていますが参考までに。
アイデア次第で何にでも使えると思います！